# What is a $G$-invariant map and why the Lie derivative is zero?

Tags: definition, symplectic-geometry, lie-derivative

I was reading the lecture notes on symplectic geometry by [Anna Cannas](https://people.math.ethz.ch/~acannas/Papers/lsg.pdf). In the Noether Theorem below, I can't find what exactly is a G-invariant map. Is it a map $f$ such that $f(g \cdot x)=f(x)$? Then why $\mathcal{L}_{X^\#}f=0$?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$G$-invariance of a function $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ indeed means that $f(g\cdot p)=f(p)$ for $g\in G, p\in M$. In other words, the function is constant on $G$-orbits.

Fix a point $p\in M$, and let's check that $(\mathcal{L}_{X^{\sharp}}f)(p)=0$. Consider the curve
$
\gamma(t):=\exp(-tX)\cdot p,
$
which satisfies
\begin{cases}
\gamma(0)=p,\\
\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\gamma(t)=X^{\sharp}(p).
\end{cases}
Now, since $f$ is $G$-invariant, we have $f(\gamma(t))=f(p)$. Differentiating this relation at time $t=0$ gives
\begin{align*}
0&=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f(\gamma(t))\\
&=(df)_{\gamma(0)}\left(\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}\gamma(t)\right)\\
&=(df)_{p}\left(X^{\sharp}(p)\right)\\
&=(\mathcal{L}_{X^{\sharp}}f)(p).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Just one more thing. This proves that if $f$ is a $G$-invariant map, then $\mathcal{L}_{v_f}\mu^X=0$. But how do you show the converse? Because of what you explained, if I have $\mathcal{L}_{v_f}\mu^X=0$, I will have $\mathcal{L}_{X^\#}f=0$, but why does this imply that for any $g\in G$ I have $f(g\cdot p)=f(p)$?

Comment: @roi_saumon I think you need the Lie group $G$ to be connected for the converse to be true. As a reference, see for instance Proposition 2.6 in "Applications of Lie groups to differential equations" by P. Olver.